# Как в Query или ActiveQuery выбрать константное значение, не из столбца?

Tags: php, yii2

В обычном запросе `SELECT` можно писать любые выражения для выборки, даже не относящиеся к какой-либо колонке какой-либо таблице. Например я могу написать `SELECT 123 as t` и это коректно вернет значение с именнованной колонкой. Как тоже самое сделать в  *Query* или *ActiveQuery*?

К примеру есть у класса константа `const TYPE_GET = 'get'`, и нужно её подставить в запрос. Сейчас я использую костыль в виде `CONCAT` или `new Expression(...)` (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression):

```
(new Query())
    ->select(['name', 'text', 'CONCAT(\'' . MyClass::TYPE_GET . '\', \'\', \'\') as alias'])    
    ->where(['id' => $id]);
```

Как записать это без такой страшной конструкции?

Comment: @HakuKimura так без разницы. Это любой подобный запрос. Ровно по аналогии c приведённым выше `SELECT 123 as t`, только тут будет к примеру `SELECT name, text, 'hello_world' as alias WHERE id = 1`

Comment: @HakuKimura при такой конструкции то, что в переменной читается как имя колонки. Её конечно же нет в таблице и будет ошибка

Comment: @HakuKimura вы не поняли суть вопроса. Мне не нужно указывать имя столбца в константе, мне нужно вывести любое значение какое я задам в этой переменной. Например `SELECT 123 as t` выведет одну ячейку со значением `123`, не смотря на то, что я даже имя таблицы не написал из которой брать данные

Comment: Что-то проще придумать вряд ли получится: `"'" . MyClass::TYPE_GET . "' AS alias"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Query())
    ->select(['name', 'text', new Expression('123 as t')])    
    ->where(['id' => $id]);
```